# How to create a vertical pure css html menu with two column submenu popups?

Tags: html, css

I would like to create a vertical pure css html menu with two columns similar to the vertical menu eBay has. Say I go onto a category there is a popup menu comes with two menus.

I know how to do a css menu, but with one column drop down. I would like the possibility to two it with two or three colunmns in the same drop down.

Thanks.

Comment: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=vertical+pure+css+menu&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a

Comment: I managed to do it with one column, now I want to do it with two. In the drop down menu I tried to add another list i.e. two lists next two each other in html.